# error foreach upload image in php/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file, controller

I'm tryng to upload image from a form in laravel but i get this in postman on dd($request->image)

Laravel version is 8.12

i have problem to get images on request , i've used/imported Request $request in my function and globally in my controller

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1900
  -test: false
  -originalName: "IMG_20211015_104550_306.jpg"
  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
  filename: "php9F5A.tmp"
  basename: "php9F5A.tmp"
  pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\php9F5A.tmp"
  extension: "tmp"
  realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\php9F5A.tmp"
  aTime: 2022-03-11 09:47:40
  mTime: 2022-03-11 09:47:40
  cTime: 2022-03-11 09:47:40
  inode: 6192449487666182
  size: 153950
  perms: 0100666
  owner: 0
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
  linkTarget: "C:\xampp\tmp\php9F5A.tmp"
}
```

in my controller:

```
 elseif ($request->type == 'Permuta') {
            $nome = $request->nome;
            $cognome = $request->cognome;
            $mailMittente = $request->email;
            $info= $request->info;
            $telefono = $request->telefono;
            $anno = $request->data;
            $info = $request->info;
            $km = $request->km;
            $cilindrata = $request->cilindrata;
            $alimentazione = $request->alimentazione;
            $targa = $request->targa;
            $marca= $request->marca;
            $modello= $request->modello;
            
            
            if (isset($request->immagini)) {
                $realPath=[];
                foreach ($request->immagini as $key => $value) {
                    $realPath[] =$value->store('images/mail', 'public');
                }
            }
            else {
                $realPath=null;
            }

            $data = [
                $request->type,
                $realPath,
                $nome,
                $mailMittente,
                $telefono,
                $anno,
                $info,
                $km,
                $cilindrata,
                $alimentazione,
                $targa,
                $marca,
                $cognome,
                $modello
            ];
            dd($request->immagini);
        }
```

i can't access to dd($value) and i get realPath=[].

Comment: I can't see your code clearly. Is there more code?

Comment: Might be helpful to see the request, what do you get when you `dd($request->file('immagini'))`?

Comment: @naamhierzo when i do `dd($request->file('immagini'))` i get the same result that i've posted before about `dd($request->immagini)`

Comment: @gguney i've add the rest of elsif code

Answer (score 0):

you try this way:

```
$file->getRealPath();
```

Comment: Hi Mr-houzi, can you elaborate a bit what your code does? Stackoverflow flagged your answer as too short (and frankly, I don't really understand how your solution fixes the issue)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for store file in storage

```
 if ($request->file('immagini')) {
            $filename = '/images/mail/' .time() . '.' . $request->file('immagini')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, file_get_contents($request->file('immagini')));
            $realPath = Storage::url($filename);
        } else {
            $realPath = null;
      }
```

Comment: this code return me a true result, but i need the file because i have to send it in a email

Comment: Can you check edited version?